# SVN commit takes a long time to find changes

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I right-click, commit from the SVN explorer extension, the dialog appears instantly but it frequently takes 30s or longer before the main pane is populated with modified files. Actually committing the changes is very fast.

Is this an inherent 'feature' of the way SVN works, that the client is having to inspect the entire file structure every time?

I don't know the repo SVN version (can I find this easily?) but the client is up to date.

Comment: Do you use local drive or network share? Size ofyour WC is ...?!

Comment: Local drive... WC hard to know because I've build the code so it's full of non-SVN files. While it's a largish project it's hardly huge by modern standards

Comment: OK, try to repeat process with fresh new checkout